# How do I add default error handling to a function which produces an iterable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, error-handling

I have a model, `Transaction`, and a method, `external_evaluation`. `external_evaluation` works its way down the stack and eventually calls out to an out to an AWS lambda. When the response is bad, a `BadResponse` exception is raised.

There is a pattern in the codebase that gets used frequently that goes something like

```rb
def get_some_transactions() 
  Transaction.where(some_column: some_expression)
end

def do_some_stuff()
  get_some_transactions.each do |transaction|
    do_something(transaction.external_evaluation)
  rescue BadResponse => e
    log(e)
    next
  end
end

def do_some_other_stuff()
  get_some_transactions.each_with_object({}) do |transaction, transaction_hash|
    transaction_hash[transaction] = do_something_else(transaction.external_evaluation)
  rescue BadResponse => e
    log(e)
    next
  end
end
```

I really dislike the duplication of the error handling code in this pattern, and would like to be able to add default error handling into `get_some_transactions` which will apply regardless of which iteration function is called (`each`, `each_with_object`, `each_with_index`, ...). Is there an idiomatic way to do this in Ruby?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def with_error_handing(&block)
  begin
    yield
  rescue BadResponse => e
    log(e)
  end
end

def do_some_stuff()
  get_some_transactions.each do |transaction|
    with_error_handing do
      do_something(transaction.external_evaluation)
    end
  end
end

def do_some_other_stuff()
  get_some_transactions.each_with_object({}) do |transaction, transaction_hash|
    with_error_handing do
      transaction_hash[transaction] = do_something_else(transaction.external_evaluation)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move the `rescue` to `external_evaluation` method.

Comment: The error should sometimes be raised and not caught. Only in the context of iterating over a set of rows in the `Transactions` table do I want to be able to set the default behaviour of logging and skipping.

Comment: You can use `yield` to pass an optional block of code to the method for customization.

Comment: Or with a simple flag `def external_evaluation(skip_exception = false)`. Later you can extend the customization as the requirements grow.

Comment: In the yield case, how do you structure it so that the user can still select which function they will use to iterate over the records?

Comment: You can reference the code Max posted above. As I understand, you would like to hook into all possible iteration methods. But it's kind of anti pattern as we should prevent any hidden logic. Instead, we should use a wrapper method or a flag, then explicitly call it in everywhere you need.